# how to connect my typescript file to server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, watch

I just got started with Angular 2 and trying to learn it.
I am using Visual Studio Code.
how can I let the server watch what happens in the typescript file? 
Should I be using some sort of compiler to javascript for that?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend that you read the docs. What server are you talking about? And yes, you should compile the typescript to javascript ( `tsc file.ts` ).

Comment: No idea what " how can I let the server watch what happens in the typescript file" means. Please elaborate a bit more what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typescript files are transpiled (converted) to Javascript before they can be useful.  This is because browsers do not execute typescript.  This means that you need to use the typescript compiler.  The server cannot directly watch what's happening (what do you mean anyhow?) in `.ts` because these files are not run directly.

Once the `.ts` becomes `.js`, it can be used as any Javascript would. If your application runs in the browser, you can let the server know what's going on by using HTTP requests as all websites do.

If you're running Javascript on the server (eg: Node) then please elaborate on what you mean. Your question is a bit confusing.

You tagged this question `angular2`, so I assume that this is the context in which you will be using Typescript.  I recommend [starting here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! 
Now the thing is, everytime i make changes in the js file the browser refreshes itself by itself and whatever changes i made appear in there. but this is not the case with the ts file.

Comment: @Sujood you're welcome. If my post answered your initial question, remember to select it.  What you're raising now is a separate issue. If you're coding in ts, you should not be manually changing the js file.  You edit the ts, then compile to js, then serve js to the browser.